# Division formula in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have 2 column Price, % of Total Price how do I get the value of % of total price using VBA.

I notice that there is no divide function for excel WorksheetFunction.Divide
so how do I loop thru my price column to get the value and dividing against the total price to get the percentage?

[image: This is the example]

Comment: Does it have to be a VBA solution when a simple formula will work?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to multiply the total by the percentage to get the value of "value of % of total price"  The other way dividing 50 by aprox 10% would give you a value of 500 which I doubt is what you want.

Comment: I trying to do this in loop format- CharlieRB

I trying to get Current cell value / Sum of total value in percentage using VBA- Damon 7

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @ejbytes definitely not.

Comment: Add a screenshot with this curent screenshot with your code. You can always cut your code and paste it with these tags to keep integrity: <pre>...mycode...</pre>

Comment: I can solve this, but I would need your code first. It's very heavily frowned upon that we submit to script writing services. Rather I can help you realize the solution to the problem, with your work as my guide :) And besides the way I'd solve this may not even make sense to you. It's better that I lead you to a (where there are many) solution rather than push what I think is a solution.

Comment: @ejbytes this problem is not a major issue :) it's http://superuser.com/questions/1083851/by-using-vba-how-do-i-compare-values?noredirect=1#comment1537873_1083851[link] that bother me more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=B53/$B$65
```

Should work.

In VBA

```
Dim x as Double
x = Range("B53").Value / Range("B64").Value
```

Just format the cell as percentage.

Comment: however I should not hard code it as (B53) due to I want to use this macro for various sheets.

Comment: Hi I'm still trying to figure out by using vba code - @Raystafarian