# By using VBA how do i compare values

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

[image: Image of my Table]

VBA code

```
   Sub loopchange()
 'select the blank column
   Dim level As String

   Range("AF2").Select
   Do
   'move to A2 cell'
   ActiveCell.Offset(0, -31).Select

   'find out which is level2
  If (ActiveCell.Value = "..2") Then

'move to column AD
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 28).Select

'Store the first 4 digit for level 2
level = Left(ActiveCell.Value, 4)

'Move to the column A3
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -28).Select 

   End If 

   MsgBox Left(ActiveCell.Value, 4)
'compare whether it's level 3(VBA don't detect this)
If (ActiveCell.Value = "...3") Then
    'move to the column AD
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 28).Select
    'compare the stored first 4 digit in level 2 known as level to first
    '4 digit of current cell
    If (level = Left(ActiveCell.Value, 4)) Then
        'move to column AF
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
        'input the word NO CTH
        ActiveCell.Value = "No CTH"
    End If

   End If
Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -31))
End Sub
```

My rationale is to compare level 2(..2) first four digit to level 3(...3) first four digit and input the world "No CTH" into column AF3 using a Do loop.

(PS my code stuck at "  If (ActiveCell.Value = "...3") Then" the vba code doesn't run this and went straight to the End if statement)

Comment: Please post your code as text, not an image, so people can copy it instead of typing everything again. Also, indent your code properly, so it becomes easier to read and more obvious to see nested statements.

Comment: Step through the code and determine what the ActiveCell.Value is in the yellow line. Is it what you expect?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply @teylyn as I'm quite new to excel vba when stepping through the code do you mean pressing f8 at the line? if it is than I have done it the code went straight to the second "End if" than the third "End if" which its not suppose to

Comment: I've removed all the spaces and indented your code. That's a lot more readable.

Comment: Was your [other question](http://superuser.com/questions/1083082/division-formula-in-excel) answered?

Comment: @Raystafarian- Thanks for asking :D As I mention previously I could not hardcode the range as the range vary differently

Comment: Please clarify: If (ActiveCell.Value = "...3") Then
What is ...3? Why would you label the cell that way? If you'll  explain, maybe I can help with your logic. I'm an experience programmer.

Comment: I just looked at the first couple lines of code and before I go on, let my add that you don't have to use ActiveCell.Offset, but you could use it to paint your cells a color to "watch" your code in action. Try using Cells(row,col). That will alleviate from bouncing around from -29 or -31 and so on. I see -31 and -29 (difference of 2 cells), not sure where you are adjusting for -2. You could be stuck in an infinite loop (unreachable code it's called). Also, step through your logic, print your page and color in the cells as you "walk your code".

Comment: @ejbytes the reason is using (ActiveCell.Value = "...3")  is because this is basically a breakdown of BOM(bill of material) "..2" and "...3" refer to the breakdown level which is level 2 and 3 respectively. My rationale is to use the first four digit of the "AD" column in lvl 2 and compare to the first four digit of "AD" column lvl 3 and if it matches I will input the word "NO CTH" in the AF column and doing this in a loop.

Comment: Aha! Try this nifty gadget, "MsgBox Left(ActiveCell.Value, 4)", without quotes. This is sort of a "print to screen", or debug method of seeing what you think you are asking for. Your .Value might be Number or Text. Ask yourself what you are asking for. And I see that you didn't initialized your Level variable, so it's a variant. Huh? Variant is whatever Excel thinks you are asking for. Instantiate properly to not get caught. e.g. Dim Level as Integer, or Dim Level as String? Also lowercase is preferred as to not confuse with Special Variables used by Excel.

Comment: @ejbytes I tried the msgbox method, it show the same value "...3" however it still went to the end if statement I will attached the updated code at next comment

Comment: The msgbox will stop your code (at that line) wherever you put a msgbox and it can display important information to you as the coder/debugger.

Comment: Do you want 'If (ActiveCell.Value = "...3")' or If '(ActiveCell.Text = "...3")' ? Note .value or .text

Comment: @ejbytes ".value" work when I tried to call "Activecell.value = "..2" so I don't see the reason why it don't work for "...3"

Comment: Okay. There are differences though. I've found out the hard way, but can't remember when I had to change my val1 = x.val to x.text. In your case, you're probably right, but just note that .text is specifically a string where a .value could be anything Excel finds it naturally to be; which could be a location in memory like an address where this value is located. Like a pointer perhaps. Something to keep in mind and doesn't hurt to try. And since you are probably running the VB often, it isn't uncommon for duplicate values to be stored in the "heap" resulting in false positive; CS note.

Comment: @ejbytes I even tried ".text" and the value still remains at "...3"

Comment: After each ActiveCell.Offset(0, xx).Select, throw in a msgbox activecell.value to make sure it's what you think it is. -31 is AF's offset. -28 looks like it's blank. And (0,+28) seems to be AC, not AD

Comment: I added a solution, or something you can work with. I didn't test it because I don't have your excel. I don't know if you can upload a copy of it in this site? But you can see where test code for debugging can really help. You'll  be surprised to see that test equality of values won't be what you thought they.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub loopchange()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim level As Integer
Range("AF3").Select
Do

ActiveCell.Offset(0, -31).Select
If ((Right(ActiveCell.Value, 1)) = 2) Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 28).Select
    level = Left(ActiveCell.Value, 4)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -28).Select
End If
If ((Right(ActiveCell.Value, 1)) = 3) Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 28).Select
       If (level = Left(ActiveCell.Value, 4)) Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
            ActiveCell.Value = "No CTH"
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Select
       ElseIf (Levels <> Left(ActiveCell.Value, 4)) Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
            ActiveCell.Value = ""
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Select
        End If
ElseIf ((Right(ActiveCell.Value, 1)) <> 2 Or (Right(ActiveCell.Value, 1)) <> 3) Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 28).Select
End If

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 3).Select
Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -31))

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

@ejbytes I solved it already.Thanks a lot for your guidances for this few days :D Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

Step through the code with F8. When you get to the critical line of code, hover over the "ActiveCell.Value" and see the pop up. Is the value of the active cell what you expect?

[image]

Your code seems to be running fine, but the data may be wrong.

Comment: @telylyn I tried hover my mouse over it show "...3" apparently the value matches but when I press f8 again it still proceed toward the End if Statement... instead of going to "ActiveCell.Offset(0,29).Select"..

Comment: Check again. Special (invisible) characters in the cell, leading or trailing blanks? If the value matches, the IF statement will go to the next command. If it goes to the EndIF then the value does not match.

Answer (score 0):

```
  
 Sub loopchange()
   'select the blank column
   Dim level As String

   Range("AF2").Select
   Do
     'move to A2 cell'
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, -31).Select

     'find out which is level2

     MsgBox ("cell = ..2?" & (ActiveCell.Value = "..2"))
     If (ActiveCell.Value = "..2") Then

       'move to column AD
       ActiveCell.Offset(0, 28).Select

       'Store the first 4 digit for level 2
       level = Left(ActiveCell.Value, 4)
       MsgBox ("Levels is set to: " & level)

       'Move to the column A3

       '**MOVE DOWN?**
       ActiveCell.Offset(1, -28).Select 

     End If 

     MsgBox ("ColA = " & (Left(ActiveCell.Value, 4)))

     'compare whether it's level 3(VBA don't detect this)


     MsgBox ("cell = ...3?" & (ActiveCell.Value = "...3"))
     If (ActiveCell.Value = "...3") Then
       'move to the column AD
       ActiveCell.Offset(0, 28).Select
       'compare the stored first 4 digit in level 2 known as level to first
       '4 digit of current cell

       MsgBox (level & "=" & Left(ActiveCell.Value, 4) & "? " & (level = Left(ActiveCell.Value, 4)))  
       If (level = Left(ActiveCell.Value, 4)) Then
         'move to column AF
         ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select

         ActiveCell.Value = "No CTH"
       End If
    End If

   'Move down one row.
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

  Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)
End Sub
```

Comment: I added msgbox's for debugging purposes and lined up the code a little.

Comment: Did you try it out with the message boxes I added?

Comment: I tried the method you show me. when I step thru the code and when it reaches this line "MsgBox ("cell = ...3?" & (ActiveCell.Value = "...3"))"  the msg box prompt me msg "mycell...3?false" what can I do to correct this

Comment: Make sure you are at the correct OFFSET. 28 or 29? MsgBox the cell value to make sure you are even looking at the right cell. That's what I mean by "logic" and "unreachable code". You are pointing to the wrong cell and comparing something contrary to your expectations.

Comment: the offset is correct Sorry that I forgot to mention that in current table cell value of column AC and AD has been swapped so the "number" value is in AC column (eg. 90119090) 

Till "MsgBox ("ColA = " & (Left(ActiveCell.Text, 4)))" the message remain at "ColA = ...3" but I don't know why when the code step thru reaches "MsgBox ("cell = ...3?" & (ActiveCell.Value = "...3"))"  it prompt me that it's false.

Comment: If it's false make sure you are comparing the values that you expect you are comparing. Print both values to the screen with msgbox and see if you are correct in your assumptions. Also realized that you are moving down a row!  Offset(row, col). Since I don't know what you're actually checking, I can't say. But did you move DOWN too early before comparing?

Comment: I updated the code to show you where you might move the OFFSET DOWN one row. Note the changes.

Comment: I've never used a chat room, but maybe it's better to move it there so I created one. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40870/vba-help

Comment: MsgBox ("cell = ...3?" & (Left(ActiveCell.Value, 4)))
     If ((Left(ActiveCell.Value, 4)) = "...3") Then
       ActiveCell.Offset(0, 28).Select

I have check the value for "(Left(ActiveCell.Value, 4))" apparently it's "...3" however when I use " If ((Left(ActiveCell.Value, 4)) = "...3") , it will went to the end if statement @ejbytes

Comment: You can't use tags like that in "comments". I added a chatroom above in comment. I'll help you there sine it's back and forth. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40870/vba-help

Comment: I don't have 20 rep yet so wont be able to use the chat room :( @ejbytes

Comment: Oh Okay. You should delete that comment, it totally warped the size of the window.

Comment: So did it work? I'm not sure what you got from that.

Comment: I have change abit from ur solution to make it move down as I want to compare the value of the current cell to "...3" and if it is I will go to column AC to get the first four value and compared to the stored one which is declare it previously as level @ejbytes

Comment: So intentionally you want to compare a row above?

Comment: yes you could say so @ejbytes